# import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js' vs import 'bootstrap'

Tags: vue.js, twitter-bootstrap, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

I've used to include bootstrap inside my `main.js` file via

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'
```

When I needed actual JS functionality (a Dropdown) it didn't work. After playing around a bit I got it working with

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap'
```

My Question: Why? Whats the difference between `bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap`? Is it Vue specific? I mean `bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css` seems to work just fine for the CSS?

(I'm still new to npm and stuff, so sorry if it's obvious.)

Edit: See comment.

Comment: This has less to do with NPM and more with whatever build tool you use

Comment: It is probably for naming conflicts. "Bootstrap" probably can't differentiate between the JS and CSS files. CSS is for presentation; JS is for interactivity. Bootstrap offers both, but they come in different packages.

Comment: @Evert So it's a VITE issue?

Comment: @FrontendC There's no issue, you didn't mention you use Vite and it's unknown what yiy tried and what didn't work. The difference is that "modular" entry point is used by modern environments that support ESM packages which Vite is, and "main https://unpkg.com/browse/bootstrap@5.3.3/package.json is used by older ones or in less common cases. Both could be workable. You're expected to use default one (import 'bootstrap'), unless you know a reason for other options.

Comment: The next thing after package.json to check is the docs that could explain entry points. Here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/contents/ it mentions "bundle" relies on global jQuery. If you didn't load it this could be the reason for it to not work, and there could be errors in the console that confirm this

Comment: @EstusFlask Thats probably it. Thanks.